# I look forward to [keep improving / keeping improving] my job

Tags: grammar

Which is correct/sounds better? The context is:

> I’m glad to have the opportunity you are giving me and so, I look
> forward to [keep improving / keeping improving] my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be "keep improving".